# Uniform stability of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

I have the following problem:

Suppose a function $f\in C(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\to\mathbb{R}^n)$ is such that $f(t,\textbf0)=0$ and
$$\textbf x^*f(t,\textbf x)\le0\quad\text{for all }(t,\textbf x)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1},
$$
where $\textbf x^*$ stands for the conjugate transposition of the vector $\textbf x$.

I am asked to prove that the equilibrium solution $\textbf x(t)=0$ of $\dot{\textbf x}=f(t,\textbf x)$ is uniformly stable, that is,

$$\forall\epsilon>0,\ \exists\delta>0\quad\text{such that}\quad |x(t_0)|<\delta\implies|x(t)|<\epsilon\quad\forall t\ge t_0.
$$
I have no idea how to start. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
(|\mathbf{x}(t)|^2)'=2\,\mathbf{x}^*(t)\ \mathbf{x}'(t)=2\,\mathbf{x}^*(t)\  f(t,\mathbf{x}(t))\le0.
$$
This shows that $|\mathbf{x}(t)|$ is decreasing.

Comment: Why not enough? Letting $ \delta $ be equal to $ \epsilon $, the stability condition is satisfied, isn't it?

Comment: You are right.  I misunderstood the definition of uniform stability, and thought it was asymptotic stability. I will delete that part of the answer.